# Non-anonymous sessions must use encryption

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to connect to the FTP using php commands. But when I try to login I get the below error

```
Warning: ftp_login(): Non-anonymous sessions must use encryption
```

Code That I have tried:

```
ftp_connect($ftp_server)
ftp_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_ASCII)
```

Though it is getting connected through FileZilla . Not sure what the error means. Thanks

Comment: What is the URL? Substitute the central name, we don't want to know what you are messing with, but we need to know if it is FTPS or FTP. What **PORT** do you connect to?

Comment: Do you log on with FileZilla as a named user?

Comment: @RowlandShaw No I just give the Host Address

Comment: @pid I am using Host Address

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you should use [FTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS) instead of FTP, this is an excerpt from the link:

> In order to maintain compatibility with existing non-TLS/SSL-aware FTP clients, implicit FTPS was expected to listen on the IANA Well Known Port 990/TCP for the FTPS control channel, and to 989/TCP for the FTPS data channel. This allowed administrators to retain legacy-compatible services on the original 21/TCP FTP control channel.

The FTP server may sit on the port you connect to, just to tell you that you need to connect to another port via FTP over SSL.

In PHP use [FTP over SSL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php): `ftp_ssl_connect()`.

Comment: Thanks but, How Do I use them ? What Php functions I shld use ?

Comment: Look at last line I've added :)

Comment: Well that's another question. You should find a tutorial or example code online.

Comment: Thanks. But Whenever I use ftp_get .I get the below                                   Warning: ftp_get(): Illegal PORT command.

Comment: You should post a new question for this with the code you have so far and the error.